# Pointers in array objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

I have a class called Customer and Car. Customer stores names and balance, and Car stores the name of cars and their price. I have read the information in from a text file to the object arrays customers and cars respectively, so there are a few customers and cars stored in these object arrays. Now I wanted to print these values out with cout by using pointers. So I did something like

```
Customer (*firstcustomer)[10] = &customers;
Car (*firstcar)[6] = &cars;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ cout << *(firstcustomer+i*2) << " " << *(firstcustomer+i*2+1) << endl;}
```

And the same for the cars thing. However, when I compile it, it prints out the address of the values, not the actual value! I dereferenced it with *. So can someone please explain to me why it does that? Thank you.

Comment: Your dereference syntax is incorrect, it should be `(*firstcustomer)[i*2]` etc. , although your loop to 10 is going to go off the end of the array

Answer (score 1):

The standard character streams don't have insertion overloads for arrays. When you insert an array, it decays to a pointer to first element of the array and you end up calling the overload that accepts a pointer to void, whose behaviour is to output the value of the pointer.

The standard character streams also don't have overloads for your user defined classes. So, unless you've defined such overloads yourself, then the following won't work:

To print the element of an array, you can use the subscript operator to access an object in a particular index of the array:

```
std::cout << (*firstcustomer)[i];
```